# JS select only one conditional element using.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

i need to select only one article that has the condition true. In the code i use hourDiff==0 as the true condition. I´m using each to iterate over the articles. In CSS i have display:none for articles. The problem in this code, is that appears all the articles before it mets the condition true.

```
<section class="noticias">
  <article class=" article element" iteridart="FL2049412">
    <script type="text/javascript"> hourDiff== 2 </script>
  </article>
  <article class=" article element" iteridart="FL2049417">
    <script type="text/javascript"> hourDiff== 0 </script>
  </article>
  <article class=" article element" iteridart="FL2045411">
    <script type="text/javascript"> hourDiff== 4 </script>
  </article>
</section>
function templateXXX {
    $(".top-right-col .noticias article").each(function(index, el){
        if(hourDiff == 0) {
        $( el ).addClass( "showClass" );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is `hourDiff` meant to be?  Think you need to calculate it rather than adding it as a global variable.  The way you have done it means that the it will always be four

Comment: @Pete sorry didn´t explain correctly, hourDiff is calculated in a function for every article.So the articles changes the value of hourDiff according to the current time. The article with hourDiff=0 can only be one article in the present time frame. What i want is to show only the article with hourDiff=0.

Comment: but if you are calculating your hour dif like that and not within some sort of function / closure, you are just updating the same variable so how would the js know which article to show?   What you probably need to do is calculate the hour diff and then add it to the article tag in a data attribute then you can test that data attribute in your each loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching this incorrectly but as a sort of workaround (searching for the text 'hourDiff== 0' in the script tag) you could do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pqjd2h5a/2/

```
$(".article").each(function(index, el){
        console.log(index);
    console.log(el);

    if($(this).text().includes("hourDiff== 0")) {
        console.log("found");
      $(this).append( "<p>hourDiff== 0</p>" )
        $(this).addClass("showClass");
    }
});
```

Ideally, you should not be having script tags as children of article elements. Is there a way to add the hourDiff as a value to each article or similar?

Comment: sorry didn´t explain correctly, hourDiff is calculated in a function for every article.So the articles changes the value of hourDiff according to the current time. The article with hourDiff=0 can only be one article in the present time frame. What i want is to show only the article with hourDiff=0.

Comment: Hey Carlos, do you want to adapt the Js-fiddle to give us a working example? https://jsfiddle.net/pqjd2h5a/2/ - You said "hourDiff is calculated in a function for every article" but what does this function look like and where is the data stored?